# weighted integral in convex hull

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, geometry

Working on an integral

$$ J=\frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}  w(t) g(e^{it}) dt                                 $$

where $\frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}  w(t) dt=1$ ; $w(t)$ is non-negative continuous function and g is analytic on closed unit disk $D$.

J "probably" lies in the convex hull of $g(D)$  but how to show that ??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: $D$ is really meant to be the _closed_ unit disk?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer yes, why not?

Comment: No problem with it. It just makes things much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $D$ is compact, and $g$ continuous, $g(D)$ is also compact. As a consequence of [Carathéodory's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_%28convex_hull%29), the convex hull $K$ of $g(D)$ is also compact.

By the Hahn-Banach theorem (gotta love overkill), for every $z\notin K$, there is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear functional $\lambda\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ and an $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(\zeta) \leqslant a < \lambda(z)$ for all $\zeta\in K$. Then

$$\lambda(J) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} w(t)\underbrace{\lambda\bigl(g(e^{it})\bigr)}_{\leqslant a}\,dt \leqslant \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} w(t)\cdot a\,dt = a < \lambda(z).$$

Hence $J\in K$.

---

The low-tech way would approximate the integral by Riemann sums in such a way that the sum is a convex combination of values of $g(e^{it})$, and since every approximating sum lies in the closed set $K$, so does the limit.